# WPF dataGgridCell Edit Mode

Tags: wpf, datagridcell, editmode

I have requirement to keep datagridcell always in edit mode. I dont find any option to make datagrid cell edit mode so I took TextBox under datagrid cell using control template.

I am able to write in text box but datagrid cell content never get updated. How I can update datagrid cell content with whatever I write in textbox ? Here is style :

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="DatagridCellWithTextbox">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ContentNormalBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                          <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <TextBox x:Name="txtCell" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Text}" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Focusable="True" />
                          </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
          </Style>
```

Thanks
Dee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [DataGridCell.IsEditing Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcell.isediting.aspx)?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

**Edit:**

You can keep in edit mode setting `Cancel` property in [DataGrid.CellEditEnding Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.celleditending) to `True`.

```
<DataGrid CellEditEnding="DataGrid_CellEditEnding"
```

.

```
private void DataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: I tried but when I done with editing, it's going back to non edit mode. I want to keep it always in editing mode

Comment: First I thought it would restore the style setter, maybe it could be even done with a style trigger for a trigger always true, but better try my new suggestion in my edit.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but I've developed my own solution recently to this.

All I do is inherit from `DataGridTextColumn` and override the `GenerateElement` method:

```
public class EditingTextBoxColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var textbox = base.GenerateEditingElement(cell, dataItem) as TextBox;
        textbox.IsReadOnly = IsReadOnly;
        return textbox;
    }
}
```

This will work for other types of column aswell.
Of course, this only works for `DataGridColumn` types that already exist (`DataGridTextColumn`, `DataGridComboBoxColumn` etc...).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I think I have a better answer.  Use a read-only DataGridTemplateColumn and set the CellTemplate.  Bindings don't work properly in CellTemplate, but you can fix that with a different RelativeSource:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Select" IsReadOnly="True">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="models:DealAcctListItem">
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource=
                           {RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}, 
                           Path=DataContext.IsSelected}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This is far easier than trying to get DataGrid's edit modes to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks Chris for posting this excellent update on such an old question. It has really helped us out. Your 2020-ish solution is much better than the rest. Let me award you some extra points. Well done.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Very nice move!